# How to create 4 arrays with one 2D array and how to scan them

Tags: java, arrays

I have to make a program about stores and sales. I have to read values from a costumer and put them in different arrays and the amount. The stores in one array, the product sold in other array and the amount of product and the price of all the products have to be in a 2d array.
I'm having struggles in that 2D array.

I've tried to read the values to all the array but when I print the 2D array it always gives me an error. I think that my problem is in "for" but I'm not sure because I'm new in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sells = 0;
    String store = "";

    System.out.print("How many sells did you make: ");
    sells = read.nextInt();

    String[] arrStores = new String[sells];
    String[] arrProduct = new String[sells];
    double[][] arrAmountPrice = new double[sells][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < sells; i++) {

        System.out.print("Store: ");
        arrStores[i] = ler.next();

        System.out.print("Product sold: ");
        arrProduct[i] = ler.next();

        System.out.print("Amount of product sold: ");
        arrAmountPrice[i][0] = ler.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Price of all the product: ");
        arrAmountPrice[i][1] = ler.nextDouble();


    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It is not a useful statement to simply say "it always gives me an error".  Please [edit] your question to include the exact text of the error.

Comment: Also I would suggest using OOP design and creating an object to hold the information, instead of three parallel `Array`'s

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import 'java.util.Scanner' or 'java.util.*' classes in order to get access to the Scanner object, then all you need to do is replace your 'ler' objects with 'read'.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sells = 0;
        String store = "";

        System.out.print("How many sells did you make: ");
        sells = read.nextInt();

        String[] arrStores = new String[sells];
        String[] arrProduct = new String[sells];
        double[][] arrAmountPrice = new double[sells][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < sells; i++) {

            System.out.print("Store: ");
            arrStores[i] = read.next();

            System.out.print("Product sold: ");
            arrProduct[i] = read.next();

            System.out.print("Amount of product sold: ");
            arrAmountPrice[i][0] = read.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Price of all the product: ");
            arrAmountPrice[i][1] = read.nextDouble();

        }
    }
}
```